# Codeception pass variables with test methods?

Tags: unit-testing, codeception

I create a new user in **testRegisterNewUser** and save username in class field variable:

```
    private $_userName;

protected function userName ()
{
    if (empty($this->_userName)) {
        $this->_userName = uniqid('test_');
    }

    return $this->_userName;
}

public function testRegisterNewUser()
{
    $user = new User($this->userName() ); // create user with random name 
}
```

After that, I try to use this value in another class method, but **$_userName** not initialized with original value from **testRegisterNewUser**!

```
public function testFundUser()
{
    $user = User::findByUsername( $this->userName() ); // fails, $this->userName() gives "non original" value
}
```

Question, is when I run tests with `codecept run`,

Is this mean that `Codeception\TestCase\Test` class recreated for every test* method call ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Codeception creates new \Test instance for each test\* method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580410/why-codeception-creates-new-test-instance-for-each-test-method)