# Why Codeception creates new \Test instance for each test* method?

Tags: codeception

As a base I use \Codeception\TestCase\Test class.

And I noticed that for every test* methods defined in class, codeception recreates TestCase\Test class !

But Why?

As result I can't use class fields!

```
public function getName() {
    if (!empty($this->_name)) {
        return $this->_name;
    } else $this->_name = uniqid('_name');
}
```

getName() for every test method will return new generated name.. thats wrong behavior as for me. It's possible to resolve this situation if I wants to use class fields for every test methods, like in normal OOP?